# How can I retrieve the last IP address of a user in Microsoft Exchange

Tags: exchange-server, ocs

I need to determine the location of (mobiles) users within the enterprise buildings & floors.

They are all using Microsoft Exchange & Office Communicator. If I have access to the IP address, I can know the location.

Is there a way to retrieve the last IP address of the user by using Microsoft Exchange or Office Communication Server API ? If yes how ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this article](https://exchangepedia.com/blog/2007/06/displaying-client-ip-address-in.html) which shows how you can display the IP Address of the current Exchange sessions.  I wasn't able to get this information to show up in Exchange 2007, but you didn't mention which version of Exchange you are using.

I don't have experience with Office Communications Server, so I can't help you there.

Comment: FWIW, looks like that link is dead.